# Change python `sys.path` permanently within a `conda` environment

Tags: python-3.x, conda, sys

For one of my projects, this happened in my local `dev` environment.

Typing:

```py
import sys 
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(sys.path)
```

gives

```py
[
 '/home/david/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/david/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/david/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/david/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/home/david/code/client1/myproject',

 '/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', # this is not DESIRED
 '/home/david/myproject2', # this is not DESIRED
]
```

The wrong PATHS have been probably added manually once doing a `pip install -e .` in some random project.

Now I want to remove the two undesired paths from `sys.path`.
I know that I can do this by using `sys.path.remove("/home/david/myproject2")`
but is there a way to do so permanently in `conda` ?
So that the next time I boot up my computer, the paths are not there anymore?

I have looked around but I see a lot of solution with `PYTHONPATH` which is not used by `conda`. On the other hand with `conda`, the proper `conda` location according to [this link](https://datacomy.com/python/anaconda/add_folder_to_path/) contains only  `/home/david/code/client1/myproject`, which is fine.

I guess there should be somewhere a `config` or some variable that contains those 2 extra paths for this specific `conda environment`. Where is it??

Comment: What doesn't work about the other answer? There are several options, all of which should remove user site (`'/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages'`). Please show which option(s) were tried and what was "not valid" about the result. Also, it's not `pip install -e` that is the problem, but `pip install --user`.

Comment: Use `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` for the ".local" one (user site), and [`PYTHONSAFEPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSAFEPATH) (which @merv answer neglects to mention) for the "myproject2" one (probably script dir). It's a bummer that conda don't exclude the user site by default in their activation script.

Comment: @merv sorry, I did not see that removing `/home/david/.local/lib/python3.8/*` actually solved the problem. Maybe it had to do that I needed a fresh reboot or terminal. Deleting that, removed both undesired paths. Thanks a lot.